# Awk parsing a math equation into variables

Tags: parsing, math, awk, equation

Well, I'm new to awk and I have an input equation like this:

```
 y = 0.02 sin(20πt-0.2πx)
```

From that equation,i want to:

-copy the `0,02` into A variable

-copy the `sin` into B variable

-copy the `20` from `20πt` into C variable

-copy the `-0.2` from `-0.2πx` into D variable

-and get rid of all the whitespace

But i don't know how to do that in awk, can somebody help me please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: awk won't honor the pi symbol as a constant. It will think it is a text char. you know about position params in awk? In your example $1="y", $2 = "=" $3="0.02" $4="....rest of it".  and change $2 to other numbers. Then you can capture data like `a=$3`. To see what I mean, try awk '{a=$3;print $2 "\t" a}' equ.file` Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by doing something like the following and work your way to cover any edge cases. Please note that this solution is extremely fragile and will not work if your input changes.

Consider this as a guide to get towards a more concrete solution based on your input data

```
$ echo 'y = 0.02 sin(20pt-0.2px)' | 
awk -F'=' '{split ($2,ary,"[ (t]"); print "a="ary[2]; print "b="ary[3]; print "c="ary[4]+0; print "d="ary[5]+0}'
a=0.02
b=sin
c=20
d=-0.2
```